# How can I use str in time.sleep()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, attributes

```
import time

t = 10
time.sleep(t)
```

This is an example.
I need to put str in time.sleep() but it gives me Attribute error: "str" object has no attribute "sleep"

Comment: The code you posted is not going to give you that error.  If you really did have a string, just do time.sleept(int(t))

Comment: If `sleep` does not accept a string argument (and of course it does not!), then you should not be looking for a way to push a string into it anyway, but you should be looking for a way to convert that string to something that fits `sleep`, i.e. a number.

Comment: Okay I get it. I defined time with another value

Answer (score 3):

Type cast your string via `int(my_str_time)`.  Though this may be a hint that sitting through a python tutorial will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

It must be converted to an int.

```
new_t = int(t)
time.sleep(new_t)
```